# How to plot a table of the results of findmaximum?

Tags: plotting, mathematical-optimization

Here is my code

```
tt[t_] := (t/(1 - t));
b[k_, n_, pf_] := \!\(\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(i = 0\), \(k\)]\(Binomial[n, i] \*SuperscriptBox[\(pf\), \(i\)] \*SuperscriptBox[\((1 - pf)\), \((n - i)\)]\)\)
l[t_, n_] := 1/(1 + tt[t]^n) - b[Floor[n/2], n, t];
Table[FindMaximum[l[t, i], {t, 0.4}], {i, 3, 501, 2}]
```

The result is as follows:

```
{{0.148148, {t -> 0.333333}}, {0.204148, {t -> 0.384677}},.....
```

I want to Listplot the data: {(0.333333,0.148148),(0.384677,0.204148),.....}

but I dont know how to manipulate the output of Table so that I can plot it. I am not able to do it manually therefore wanted to ask it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
results= Table[FindMaximum[l[t, i], {t, 0.4}], {i, 3, 501, 2}]

ListPlot[Transpose[{t /. results[[All, 2]], results[[All, 1]]}]]
```

[image]

**Explanation**

`results[[All, 1]]` takes all the `y` values

`t /. results[[All, 2]]` replaces the rules creating a list of all the `t` values

`Transpose` to have it ready for `ListPlot`

Answer (score 2):

And still another method is

```
ListPlot[Cases[results, {z1_, {Rule[_, z2_]}} :> {z2, z1}, Infinity]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

That's like a breeze:

```
result = {{0.148148, {t -> 0.333333}}, {0.204148, {t -> 0.384677}}}

Flatten /@ result /. x_Rule :> x[[2]] // ListLinePlot
```

PS: Because there are only 2 points better using `ListLinePlot` for illustration

Comment: When I try this it appears that the x and y axis are flipped

Answer (score 1):

Let `tab` be the results table:

```
ListPlot[{t /. #2, #1} & @@@ tab]
```

Comment: Very terse as is your answer. I like it but don't quite understand it. Could you elaborate a bit as to what is going on?

Comment: @JackLaVigne this merely takes the result `tab` and converts into the coordinates...`t/.#2` extractst from  the rule and `#1`the maximum

Comment: I get it now. `{t /. #2, #1}&` is a pure function that works on each element of the tab list. Each element is a list and the symbol @@@ replaces the head of each element with this pure function. So (taking the first element as an example) argument #1 is 0.148148 and argument #2 is {t -> 0.3333}.

Answer (score 0):

```
dt = Quiet@ Table[{Last@@#2, #1}&@@ FindMaximum[l[t, i], {t, 0.4}], {i, 3, 501, 2}];

ListPlot[dt]
```

[image]

You could also use:

```
dt = Quiet@ Table[{Last @@ #, #2} & @@ 
            Reverse@FindMaximum[l[t, i], {t, 0.4}], {i, 3, 501, 2}];
```